# How do you empty a linux directory with a large size/number of files?

Tags: linux, delete-file

I have a directoy in linux that has several hundred thousand files, and is about 100 Gb.  I attempted to clear out the directory using 'rm -f *', and got the following error:

```
>rm -f *
-ksh: rm: /bin/rm: cannot execute [Argument list too long]
```

I get the same error when I try the find command. I can delete individual files, and groups if I can get a small enough expression, but that could days to clear them all out.  Does anyone know any better ways to empty a large directory?

Comment: Does the files names have any pattern? So you could write a script to iterate over them. You can write a script to delete them in groups even if they don't.

Comment: Actually, it's usually better to delete the entire directory (`rm -rf dir`) and recreate it, than to empty it.

Comment: It is a duplicate, I did not find that question when searching before I posted.  I will try the -xargs suggestion from that thread.

Comment: Related: [Does "argument list too long"
 apply to shell builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443380/does-argument-list-too-long-restriction-apply-to-shell-builtins)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
rm -R -f [your_directory_path]
```

Then just manually recreate your directory, this way is easier I believe than what you are trying to do:

```
mkdir [old_directory_name]
```

Comment: I did consider this, the problem is I only have permissions on the files inside the directory.  The actual directory itself is read only for me.  Obviously I could get an infrastructure admin to do it, but not many of those available for a Dev issue on a Saturday evening :)

Comment: put a star at the end of the directory name in Ubuntu eg /*

Comment: @AZ_ won't that give the same "Argument list too long" error?

Comment: @izogfif The error “Argument list too long” occurs when the number of arguments provided to a command exceeds the system’s maximum limit. This is a kernel limitation on the size of the command line argument. It should not occur for 'rm -R -f [dir path]'